# Laravel showing HTTP ERROR 500 after moving to shared server

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

I have a local project in laravel which i moved to my shared hosting. As per tutorials available on the net i zip the file and uploaded into `public_html` directory of my server and extracted all its file into that. Then took out the `index.php` file from the laravel `public` folder and changed it a bit

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

After then when i refresh the page its showing HTTP ERROR 500. I tried to run the same code on XAMP its working perfectly fine but not on the server. What could be reason ??

Btw, i also like to mention i have .htaccess enable  to route domain from not www not https to https://www.mydomainname.com

My .htaccess is as follows

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Can anyone please fix this issue??

Comment: have you checked the laravel logs?

Comment: Sounds like a CHMOD issue i.e Permissions with the files themselves. Try CHMOD'ing them to 755 (I think that'll do it)

Comment: First, you should check the laravel logs and your PHP logs as @pseudoanime suggests - if it is a 500 error, there will be a log for it somewhere. Two, this is a common issue if the permissions on your storage folder and your bootstrap/cache folder are not set to be writable.

Comment: Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix. It was the issue with the PHP Version my php version was set to 5.1 but it need atleast php 7.